# Convergence rule proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

in my Mathmatics Script the following rule is given:

Let $x_n$ be a real sequence with Limit x $\neq 0$. Then there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ in a way that $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n \ge 0$ and 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{x_n})_{n \ge n_0 }=\frac{1}{x}$$

Now I want to proof that but I really don't have any clue on how to do that. I have been thinking about this Problem for a while now and I haven't gotten anything useful yet.

The best Thing I thought of was the following:

$x_n \ge \frac{1}{x_n}$ for $x_n \ge 1$. Therefore:

$$|\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{x}| \le |x_n - x| \le \epsilon $$

But that just prooves that $\frac{1}{x_n}$ converges for $x_n \ge 1$ right? I am soory but I don't have a clue...

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent to $x\ne0$ so it's a bounded below:

$$\exists m>0 \quad m\le|x_n|,\;\forall n\ge n_0$$
hence we have

$$\left|\frac1{x_n}-\frac 1 x\right|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{|xx_n|}\le \frac{|x_n-x|}{m|x|}\to0$$
and we conclude.

Comment: Aww - ya that makes it clear. Thank you that helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome Funky.

Answer (score 1):

Since the limit of the original sequence exists and is non-zero, there can only be finitely many zeros in the original sequence. This guarantees you can find $n_0$ so that $x_n \neq 0$ for $n \geq n_0$. As for why $\lim_{n \to \infty, n \geq n_0} 1/x_n = 1/x$, you can use the fact that $f(x) = 1/x$ is a continuous function and there is a theorem that says that if if $\lim x_n = x$ then $\lim f(x_n) = f(x)$ for any continuous function $f$. If you'd like a proof of that theorem I can provide it, and you can substitute $f(x) = 1/x$ to see how the proof works in your case.

Comment: Whops I am so sorry! I have made a fatal mistake in my question. N is defined in $\mathbb{N}$ - not $\mathbb{R}$. Damn I am so sorry..